# Embedly tutorial/example no longer working?

Tags: html, embed

I've been  using a modification of [embedly's tutorial](http://embed.ly/docs/tutorials/simple) to embed thumbnails of photos onto my website. It's been working really well so far, though recently it hasn't been embedding my photos and figured I'd maybe messed something up, but looks like somehow this service is not working any more.

If you put in the exact code they give you on their website and run it, it clearly does not work any more and does not embed anything.

Am I missing something? Is anyone else able to get this code working?

**EDIT** This is what my page looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozXrx.gif

**EDIT** Working jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/enderx475/7axFD/

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://scripts.embed.ly/jquery.embedly.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('document').ready(function(){
    $('div.content').embedly({
      maxWidth: 450,
      wmode: 'transparent',
      method: 'after'
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
  <article>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorizzle ma nizzle dolor sit amizzle, brizzle adipiscing elit. </p>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbcgyPtYBY0">youtube</a>
    <p>Maecenizzle owned bow wow wow. Nam eros.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <p>Lorizzle ma nizzle dolor sit amizzle, brizzle adipiscing elit. </p>
    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/churchclothing/2597225382/">flickr</a>
    <p>Maecenizzle owned bow wow wow. Nam eros.</p>
  </article>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My embedly videos also just stopped working.  Looks like they are requiring an API key now.  Not sure when this change happened, but it seems to be recent.

After you sign-up here: http://embed.ly/pricing

You get a key and then need to pass that as a param when calling embedly.  Make sure you also have the latest version of the jquery javascript file, as it is set up to look for the key.

Comment: One thing that is problematic for me, is that my key is plainly visible, and could easily be stolen and used on another site which would drive my links up (and that is a problem now that I am restricted to 10k/month).

Comment: Shit, you're right. My key is sitting out in the open. Good catch.

Comment: From embedly support:

Hi Mike,

We are in the process of adding a referrer lock to API keys. This will
reject any calls that don't have the referrer that you have setup in our
system. Of course, this isn't a foolproof system. There isn't a simple way
to provide tough security for a client side implementation, especially on a
public site. We realize this, and if there is ever a question of where your
calls are coming from, let us know and we will make sure you don't have to
pay for anything you didn't use.

Thanks
Bob Corsaro

Comment: I got the exact same response, word for word, from the same guy. Apparently they haven't done a good job with this basic security they claim to have because my site somehow went thru nearly 3000 URLs yesterday which is impossible.

Comment: They've added referrer support:

Mike,

Referrer locking is now in place. You can add referrers by logging into http://app.embed.ly/ and clicking "Manage" in the "Manage your Referrers" box. Please feel free to email us with any other questions.

Bob Corsaro

Answer (score 1):

This code works perfectly for me localy. Try [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/). Maybe browser caching problem?